# Python - Algorithm to determine if a list is symmetric

Tags: python

So I'm stuck on this problem where I've been asked to write an function in Python that checks to see if an n-dimensional array (is that what they're called?) is "symmetric" or not, meaning that row 1 of the array == column 1, row 2 == column 2, row 3 == column 3, etc so on and so forth. The goal is to have a function that returns the boolean True if its symmetric, and False if its not.

I've managed to write a function that works, but it only work on lists whose sizes are perfect squares, (e.g 2 x 2, 4 x 4), and a few of my test cases are of "irregular" sizes (e.g 2 x 5, 3 x 2). For those lists I end up getting a list index out of range error Code here:

```
def symmetric(square):
    final_result = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while x < len(square):
        row_list = []
        col_list = []
        while y < len(square[x]):
            print "(x, y): %d, %d" % (x, y)
            print "(y, x): %d, %d" % (y, x)
            row_list.append(square[x][y])
            col_list.append(square[y][x])
            y = y + 1
        if row_list == col_list:
            final_result.append(True)
        else:
            final_result.append(False)
        x = x + 1

    for x in final_result:
        if x == False:
            return False
    return True
```

And the test cases that I'm failing on here:

```
print symmetric([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [2, 3, 4, 5],
                [3, 4, 5, 6]])
#Expected result: >>> False
#List index out of range

# This one actually returns the correct result, I'm just including it here
# for reference.
#print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
#                ["dog", "dog", "fish"],
#                ["fish", "fish", "cat"]])
#Expected result: >>> True
#Actual result: >>> True


print symmetric([[1,2,3],
                 [2,3,1]])
#Expected Result: >>> False
#Actual result: list index out of range
```

Can someone help me modify the code so that it will work on these "irregularly shaped" arrays?

Comment: _"a few of my test cases are of "irregular" sizes"_ - by your definition, these _cannot_ be symmetric, since `row 1 == column 1` cannot hold true.

Comment: Please update your indentation.  I think everything but the function definition needs indented, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @Eric it looks like his expected output for such cases is `False`.

Comment: @robert: He hasn't made it clear which results are expected and which are the actual results.

Comment: @Eric I thought the "Expected result: >>> False" near the beginning of his second code block was clear.

Comment: @robert: Not clear that there's a problem with the last test though. He says "he's failing on these tests", yet the last one appears to succeed.

Comment: Why append to that final result? If you have a hit with False, return False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this check at the start of your function:

```
for row in square:
    if len(row) != len(square):
        return False
```

Or maybe shorter

```
if not all(len(square) == len(row) for row in square): return False
```

Comment: No need for parentheses in python `if` statements

Comment: @Eric, and this this considered a bad style, right? I'm just a newcomer to python, should I always omit them when possible?

Comment: Absolutely. Only use parentheses in an if statement to aid line-wrapping long conditions

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Check out [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the python style guide. Basically, the use of redundant parens is best left to multi-line statements.

Comment: You can use `any` as well and avoid the `not`: `if any(len(square) != len(row) for row in square)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I know that style means a lot to python, will study that, up until now I only read http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html, but maybe I need a second read-through to remember, thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see `not all` a bit more logical from my point of view, I'm trying to insure the constraints instead of looking for violations, is that ok in python? :)

Comment: Sure, that's why I worded it as a suggestion. :-P

Answer (score 9):

This bit of code will do it all for you:

```
def symmetric(square):
    square = [tuple(row) for row in square]
    return square == zip(*square)
```

In your solution you're doing too much of the work yourself.  Python will compare sequences for you, so an easier method is to transpose the square so its rows become columns and vice versa and then compare it to the original value.

We can transpose the square using [the zip function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).  This takes a number of sequences and returns a tuple containing first of each and then a tuple with the second of each and so on.  By passing `square` as `*square` we pass each row as a sperate argument; this has the effect of transposing the square.

The only complication is that `zip` returns tuples not lists so we have to make sure `square` is a list of tuples so the comparison works.

Comment: this is actually a really cool use of zip that i hadn't thought of before

Comment: +1 for the great usage of zip and * to pass several arguments!

Comment: Code golf anyone? I'd actually posted this as my own answer, but deleted it as too similar to this one: `symmetric = lambda sq: list(map(tuple,sq))==zip(*sq)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative version for the main test:

```
for i, line in enumerate(matrix):
    for j in range(len(line)):
        if a[i][j] != a[j][i]:
             return False
return True
```

Of course that all the other answers that advise you to test if the matrix is square hold true.

Comment: Wow that's even better than what I had. I guess I took the long way around, eh?

Comment: Sometimes the challenge with python is to take advantage of the language enough to keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add this near the beginning:

```
for row in square:
    if len(row) != len(square):
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

A version for Python3

```
def symmetric(L)
    return all(i==j for i,*j in zip(L ,*L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Value `y = 0` should be inside the first while loop. Like this:

```
def symmetric(square):
    final_result = []
    x = 0
    while x < len(square):
         y = 0
        row_list = []
        .
        .
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you're posting answers please format the code so that it's readable.