# compare the row and column in a list using python function

Tags: python, list, compare, symmetry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Algorithm to determine if a list is symmetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228939/python-algorithm-to-determine-if-a-list-is-symmetric)

I need help writing a Python function - symmetric,that takes as input a list of size n(which is a square matrix) that checks the first row is the same as the first column, the second row is the same as the second column and so on, and returns boolean True if the elements are the same and false if they are not. The list could contain integers or strings.

```
def symmetric(my_list):

my_list = [[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 3, 4],
           [3, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: Is this homework? Try posting some of your attempts before asking us to do your task for you

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, heh I outgolfed you :)

Comment: Hi, This is what I have tried so far and I get a sytax error message:

Comment: Hi, this is what I have tried so far:

def symmetric(p):
 size = len(p) 
 i = 0
 while i < size:
  j = 0
  while j < size
   if p[i][j] != p[j][i]
    return False
  j = j + 1
 i = i + 1
 return True

I get a syntax error message

Answer (score 4):

This works in Python2

```
my_list == map(list, zip(*my_list))
```

`zip(*some_2d_list)` is a fairly well known idiom, when `some_2d_list` is unpacked and processed by `zip` it has the effect of transposing the rows and columns

Unfortunately zip returns a list of tuples, so it is necessary to convert those to lists. This is what `map(list, ...)` does

It may appear wasteful as testing for equality will compare each pair that are not on the diagonal twice, but this is done at the C level, so will be much faster than using explicit loops and doing the minimum number of comparisons.

If it is homework, I'd suggest that you should probably use nested loops

EDIT: In Python3, `map(...)` returns a map object, you can get the Python2 behaviour by using `list(map(...))`

EDIT: I think in Python3, this is better

```
all(i==j for i,*j in zip(my_list ,*my_list))
```

Comment: +1, you can add an edit about python 3.x: `map()` returns a map object in python 3.x, so the comparison will return `False` in python 3.x

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I thought of a neater way to do it in Python3

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
# convert the 2d list into an ndarry
x = np.array(my_list)
# test if x is identical to its transpose
isSymmetric = (x.T == x).all()
```

`isSymmetric` then tells you the result.